# C# CheckBox List Selected Items.Text to Labels.Text

Tags: c#, label, checklistbox

I have a CheckBoxList and 5 labels.

I would like the text value of these Labels to be set to the 5 selections made from the CheckBoxList after the user clicks on a button.  How would I get this accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- bind an event to a button,
- iterate trough the `Items` property of the `CheckBoxList`
- set the text value according to the `selected` property of the `listitem`

like:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in theCheckBoxList.Items)
    {
        item.Text = item.Selected ? "Checked" : "UnChecked";
    }
}
```

to add a value you could do:

```
 foreach (ListItem item in theCheckBoxList.Items)
 {
        item.Text = item.Selected ? item.Value  : "";
 }
```

or display al values in a mini-report:

```
    string test = "you've selected :";
    foreach (ListItem item in theCheckBoxList.Items)
    {
        test += item.Selected ? item.Value + ", " : "";
    }
    labelResult.Text = test;
```

Comment: Is there a way I could make each selection a different label.text value?  That would make inserting the values into a different SQL table column much easier.

Answer (score 1):

find selected items from CheckboxList by Lambda Linq:

```
var x = chkList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected);
    if (x!=null && x.Count()>0)
    {
         List<ListItem> lstSelectedItems = x.ToList();            
         //... Other ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have *one* label and on the button click do something like:

```
foreach (var li in CheckList1.Items)
{
   if(li.Checked)
      Label1.Text = li.Value + "<br />";
}
```

That may not be the exact syntax but something along those lines.

Comment: Because I plan on taking each label value, asking the users to confirm selections, then once they confirm the selection I will then insert each value into a different DB column.

Comment: Ok, but you can insert your values into the DB by still using your CheckBoxList.Items. The values will still be selected. You can write a method that iterates through your CheckBoxList selected items, then insert each one into your required DB columns.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to that would iterate through each checked item, then insert each one into the correct column?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in LINQ:

```
foreach (var cbx3 in CheckBoxList2.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cbx3 => cbx3.ID == s))
{
    cbx3.Checked = true;
}
```